# BIOS Recovery for Lenovo Ideapad U410

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I'm stuck while trying to recover an corrupted EFI / Insyde BIOS. Right now the laptop is in a state, that when the power button is pushed, the computer turns on and immediately off again.

I downloaded a self-extracting archive from [Lenovo support](http://support.lenovo.com/de/de/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-u-series-laptops/ideapad-u410/downloads/DS101011). After that I followed the advices from several internet boards and copied the file `65CN99WW.cap` to a FAT32 formatted USB stick with less than 2GB. After that I renamed that file to `BIOS.cap`. I then inserted the stick in a completely unpowered (no battery, no AC). Then I held down `FN-R` plugged in power again while holding and finally pushed the power button. After that I saw the USB stick blinking for some seconds, which means it has been read. But after some seconds (but a period significantly longer than without the usb stick and any other key combination) the laptop turns off again.

So my question is, if there is some documentation or instructions out there how to recover an EFI / Insyde BIOS on a Lenovo Ideapad U410.

Comment: This information normally is contained in the manual.  At least it is for my Lenovo.

Comment: May I ask, which manual you are talking about? I had a look at the hardware maintenance manual and the user guide. None of them talk about BIOS recovery.

Comment: Do you know if the POST tests in the BIOS do terminate? And which version of Windows?

Comment: As far as I can say, there happens no POST test at all. The power turns off immediatly after I push the on/off button. The screen remains dark.
Windows 8.1 was installed before the BIOS update. (But I don't get, why that is of any importance)

Comment: There is a part of the story missing: "Why do you think your BIOS is corrupt? How did it end up in that state? Why did you do that?" This part is crucial because it identifies how to make your laptop functional again, not just its BIOS; it focuses on how and why it broke, giving more surrounding details.

Comment: So, my girlfriend reinstalled windows on the laptop. And she dutiful downloaded all the files from the Lenovo support files and wanted to install the drivers. The file list also includes a BIOS update. She started installing, the computer booted in DOS mode, she got scared and turned of the computer. So my assumption was then, that due to an interruped flashing procedure, and the computer not doing a POST, the BIOS is corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Found [this procedure](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-S-series-Netbooks/LENOVO-BIOS-RECOVERY/td-p/332989) :

1. [Download Phoenix Wincrisis](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ztmilmmeymr/Use+Crisis+Recover+Disk+with+Pen+Drive.rar) on another computer, then Click on `WINCRIS.exe` and choose `CREATE MINIDOS CRISIS DISK` and press `START` to make: USB floppy or USB flash memory.
   When creating, select from `Folder Options` to view the hidden and system files and delete or rename the file `config.sys` if present. Read also the included instructions.
2. Rename your BIOS file (65CN99WW.cap?) to bios.wph and copy it to the USB stick.
3. Plug the USB stick into the laptop and shutdown.
4. Hold down the keys <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and while holding press the power button.
5. Now you should hear the floppy drive working or USB blinking. Hold the keys for a while.
6. Leave the computer for few minutes. If it does not restart itself, turn the power off.
7. if everything went OK the computer should start normally.

Note: Do not take off your battery before flashing. It seems that it will verify AC/DC connection and battery level and stop if one is not OK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the BIOS you can download for the Ideapad u410 from the Lenovo homepage is not a Phoenix one. So the above procedure does NOT work.

Comment: I have managed to find other sources, such as [this one](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1/Anyone-managed-Win-8-on-an-Ideapad-U410-U310-yet/td-p/849937/page/2) that confirm that the BIOS is in fact Phoenix. If you have installed another BIOS, then this might be the reason why the computer doesn't boot any more.

Comment: So I really tried the procedure you referenced and copied here, but unfortunately it does not work. I see that the USB stick is read, but the Laptop turns off immediatly again.

Comment: A thread discussing this process can be [found here](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/Lenovo-ideaPad-Y560-BIOS-Recovery/td-p/377911). I suggest to read it all - it might help with the fine points.

Comment: Read it a few times and/or take notes, there are quite a few things that can go wrong with this one.

Comment: Fixing a bricked computer is always chancy. The last refuge is as always the repair-shop.