# BIOS USB Recovery for Lenovo Ideapad 15ALC6

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop, post

I bought this laptop for cheap hoping to repair it. It came with solid lights on esc, caps lock and num lock. After doing some testing (display, power, other components) it seems that it got bricked during a BIOS update, as many others did (a quick search shows this was common). Other than replacing the entire motherboard, which is too expensive to be worth it, my choices seem to be (hardest to easiest):

1. Remove the bios chip using hot air, and either replace it with a new one, or flash it with CH341a.
2. Use a clip and the CH341a to flash it while still attached to the board.
3. Use a USB to flash it in crisis mode.

Right now, I want to try #3 first, and can get the laptop to crisis mode using Fn+R, which turns off the keyboard lights, and makes the orange light flash on the side. I have downloaded the BIOS (GLCN52WW), and extracted the other files from the EXE, but the actual bios file does not have an extension. I have attempted to rename it and give it various extensions (rom, wph, fd, bin), and then copy those to a USB, including using WINCRISIS, and other things that people have tried in similar cases, but the dead laptop doesn't seem to be able to recognize the file to be able to flash it.

Does anyone know how I would find the correct filename/extension to give the bios so that it can be flashed in crisis mode? I have searched extensively and asked Lenovo, but can't find an answer.

Helpful reading:

- [Lenovo B490 BIOS Recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/1787243/lenovo-b490-bios-recovery)
- [Extract BIOS .fd file from .exe on Acer Aspire E1-571](https://superuser.com/questions/1247166/extract-bios-fd-file-from-exe-on-acer-aspire-e1-571)

Comment: One more link: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Laptops/Recovery-bios-for-Ideapad-3-15ALC6/m-p/5240272

Comment: Letting the self-extracting file run under Sanboxie, WinFlash64.exe, BIOS.cap, GLCN52WW.exe, install.bat and SctWinFlash64.exe were created in C:\Drivers\Flash. Is BIOS.cap the needed file, or is it further hidden in  one of the two executables, which I could not extract?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Perhaps; I see that the .cap file might be a .bin with a header, which I would need to cut off (not great with that stuff), but I'll try it just with the cap

Comment: @DrMoishePippik couldn't get it to work with that

Comment: "bios.wph" (?) (have you a Phoenix BIOS Crisis ? (found here (harrymc's answer): https://superuser.com/questions/809412/bios-recovery-for-lenovo-ideapad-u410?rq=1 )

Comment: If you flashed the BIOS yourself it should have created a backup of the original BIOS, you might  want to flash it with the Original BIOS first, if you have that.

Comment: @vssher I tried that Phoenix method, didn't work. And the backup is not available to me.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I ended up doing option #2 in my post (reflashing the BIOS using an EEPROM programmer) and I copied the BIOS file (.bin) straight from another laptop of the exact same model. If anyone who has the same issue wants the file, and finds this post, just leave a comment.

Comment: Did this help solve the Lights problem you had in the beginning? It is now a usuable laptop?

Comment: @vssher yup! Fully usable, running windows 11 smoothly.